# My Ubuntu 20.04 only uses Single Core

Tags: cpu

Now I am using Ubuntu 20.04 but when I use some GUI applications(rviz, VSCode, Firefox) and playing bagfiles(logging data of ROS), it becomes really slow.

When I check with lscpu command, it shows as below.

CPU(s):                1

On-line CPU(s) list:   0

Thread(s) per core:    1

Core(s) per socket:    1

Socket(s):             1

...

Model name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10850H CPU @ 2.70GHz

...

I am using HP ZBook Create 15 G7 Mobile Workstation(Intel Core i7-10850H 6-core 12-thread) so model name is correct, but number of CPU Cores and Threads are completely different.

I also checked with system monitor and it only shows one single thread.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What GUI applications? What video card and driver?

Comment: We can safely assume Ubuntu is installed on hardware and not as a virtual machine?

Comment: @David
Right now I am using rviz (visualizer of ROS), VSCode, and firfox( sorry it wasn't chrome).

Comment: @vanadium
No. I'm not using virtual machine.

Comment: Is multi-threading enabled in BIOS / Hardware setup ?

Comment: Also, try to plug into an AC outlet and see if the output is the same. I know sometimes it's throttled on battery power but not usually reduced to a single core but it's worth a shot.

Comment: @SorenA
I think yes. I am not sure this Hyper-Threading is the one you are talking about.
I cannot find other items that is mentioning about threads.

Comment: @mchid
Yes. I am using AC outlet all the time.
When I don't use it, it becomes really really slow that it makes me want to punch the display.

Comment: Have any cpu governing tools been installed? Is there a custom configuration in your grub configuration? It’s odd that you’re system would operate like this with a stock installation 

Comment: I have seen a machine needing acpi=0 to boot, but then only ran single core. Solution was to update the firmware, then acpi kernel param was not needed, and all cores were seen. (Ryzen 5 2400G)

Comment: @matigo
I don't really know about cpu governing tools but I haven't customized cpu configuration by myself, and installed that kind of libraries.

Comment: @ubfan1
I updated firmware of my PC (and also other updates programs) but the result was same. Still runs with single core.

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved this problem... 
The only way to solve this was a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04. 
I couldn't find out why this issue happened, but now it is working fine.